# Angular2 and objects "Error property does not exist in type"

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have this model "opcionesautocomplete.model.ts"

```
interface IOpcionesAutocomplete {
    opcionesStyle: OpcionStyle;  
    pcionPropiedades: OpcionPropiedades;
}

export class OpcionesAutocomplete implements IOpcionesAutocomplete {      
     opcionesStyle: OpcionStyle;
     opcionPropiedades: OpcionPropiedades;
    constructor()  { }
}

interface IOpcionStyle {
    width: number;
    height: number; 
    isOverflowY: boolean;
}

export class OpcionStyle implements IOpcionStyle {
      width: number;
      height: number; 
      isOverflowY: boolean;
    constructor()  { }
}

interface IOpcionPropiedades {
    propiedad1: string;
    propiedad2: string; 
    textoEtiqueta: string;
}

export class OpcionPropiedades implements IOpcionPropiedades {
    propiedad1: string;
    propiedad2: string; 
    textoEtiqueta: string;
    constructor()  { }
}
```

Now I am trying to fill the object in my component with all its objects but angular2 return error "mycmp.component.ts":

```
import { OpcionesAutocomplete, OpcionStyle, OpcionPropiedades } from './../../shared/forms/autocomplete/opcionesautocomplete.model';

export class.... {

    opcionStyle = new OpcionStyle();
    opcionPropiedades = new OpcionPropiedades();

    opcionesAutocompleteClientes : OpcionesAutocomplete = new OpcionesAutocomplete();

    ...

    fillObject(){       
        this.opcionStyle.width=550;
        this.opcionStyle.height=150;
        this.opcionStyle.isOverflowY=true;    
        this.opcionesAutocompleteClientes.opcionStyle = this.opcionStyle; //The error is here
    }   
}
```

The error is in de line:

```
this.opcionesAutocompleteClientes.opcionStyle = this.opcionStyle;
```

"Property opcionStyle does not exist in type "OpcionesAutocomplete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misstyped

```
this.opcionesAutocompleteClientes.opcionesStyle = this.opcionStyle;
```

You class is

```
export class OpcionesAutocomplete implements IOpcionesAutocomplete {      
     opcionesStyle: OpcionStyle;
     opcionPropiedades: OpcionPropiedades;

     constructor()  { }
}
```

which has `opcionesStyle`, not `opcionStyle`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a typo, change it to:

```
this.opcionesAutocompleteClientes.opcionesStyle = this.opcionStyle;
```